# Java ArrayList, access method to return ArrayList of abstract class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, abstract

I have an `ArrayList` containing objects derived from an abstract class, is there a way to return the an array list of the abstract class type then, using polymorphism, be able to reference the origin object?

The only way I can see of doing this is to create an `ArrayList` of the abstract class type, then copy the elements from the original `ArrayList` into this, but I don't want copies.

Comment: Post your code, and tell us precisely what you would like to do that is not possible with what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose your concrete class is `Integer` and your abstract class, `Number`.

If you are willing to receive a result cast as a `List<Number>` instead of an `ArrayList<Number>` (a good practice anyway), you can do something like the following:

```
List<Integer> listOfConcrete = new ArrayList<>(); // your actual list
List<Number> listOfAbstract = listOfConcrete.stream()
  .map(n -> (Number) n)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need the explicit cast in the `map()` call so that the casting is performed properly.

Comment: Wow, that was quick, I used your example and it works great, my method looks like this:  public ArrayList<clsPoll> alobjGetPollSchedule() { retrurn (ArrayList<clsPoll>)malobjPollSchedule.stream().map(n -> (clsPoll)n).collect(Collectors.toList()); }

Comment: No, you don’t need the explicit cast in `map`. Actually, you don’t need the `map` step at all. `listOfAbstract = listOfConcrete.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());` is sufficient. But you don’t even need Java 8 to copy a list: `List<Number> listOfAbstract = new ArrayList<>(listOfConcrete);` works as well.

Comment: And if the goal is to consume the List<Integer> as numbers, maybe all is needed is `List<? extends Number> listOfAbstract = listOfConcrete;`, which doesn't need any copy. But the OP should really clarify, so that we know.